# Сделать  эффект появления

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!
Пример : http://www.revox.io/webarchb3/index.html

Через 5 секунд справа вверху (на иконке человечка) появляется красный кружек. Каким образом можно сделать такой же эффект появления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом примере используется [animate.css](https://daneden.me/animate/) эффект bounceIn. Если нужно на jquery, то [Эффект Show jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/show/) эффект scale. И, как пример, для Вас [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mRcUP/).

HTML

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<div id="block"></div>
```

CSS

```css
#block{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
    $( "#block" ).show( "scale", {}, 300, {} );
});
```